# MySQL bottleneck on AMD A-10 witn 12BG of RAM?

Tags: mysql, python, database-performance

Running the identical python script that parses XML and inserts records into MySQL using MySQLdb package for python, I'm experiencing very different load times between a Mac Mini i5 with 8GB of RAM (OS High Sierra), and an HP Pavilion with an AMD A-10 with 12GB of RAM (Ubuntu 16.04).

The Mac Mini inserts the records at about 100 per second, while the AMD A-10 only inserts about 1 record per second.  I initially thought it was because I was running full drive encryption, but after a fresh install of Ubuntu without drive encryption, the database is still bottlenecked to 1 insertion per second.

What can I do to trouble-shoot the bottleneck on the AMD machine in Ubuntu?

I checked the free memory on the AMD and about half of the RAM is still free, the swap space was not used at all. Otherwise, I'm at a loss of what to check to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Try tuning the MySQL performance settings. If there is any issue with the performance settings then you may face this issue. You can also try disabling vacuum. Single record per second is very low. We are doing 3000 records per second.